# How to join documents with AngularFire2?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I have a list of IDs to another document in Firebase, like this:

```
{
  uid,
  members: [0, 1, 3],
  ...
},
```

I'm currently joining the member object like this:

```
af.database.list('/threads')
  .map((message) => {
     message.members = message.members.map((memberID) => {
       return af.database.object('/users/' + memberID);
     });
 });
```

Is there a cleaner way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea is to create a `ThreadComponent` that will pass the member ids to child `MemberComponent` that handles member data.

**threads.component.html**

```
<div class="thread" *ngFor="let thread of threads$ | async">
  <my-member *ngFor="let memberId of thread.members"
    [memberId]="memberId"></my-member>
</div>
```

**threads.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFire } from 'angularfire2';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-thread',
  templateUrl: 'thread.component.html',
  // ...
})
export class MyThreadComponent implements OnInit {
  threads$;

  constructor (private af: AngularFire) {}
  ngOnInit () {
    this.threads$ = this.af.database.list('/threads');
  }
}
```

**member.component.html**

```
<div>{{ memberInfo$ | async }}</div>
```

**member.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFire } from 'angularfire2';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-member',
  templateUrl: 'member.component.html',
  // ...
})
export class MyMemberComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() memberId;
  memberInfo$;

  constructor (private af: AngularFire) {}
  ngOnInit () {
    this.memberInfo$ = this.af.database.list(`/users/${memberId}`);
  }
}
```

The one problem I can see with your current method is that it looks like you might be mutating the returned observable from angularfire, which may cause undesirable effects. You can create a different variable and set the returned member firebase observables to that instead.